# Groupon Style Swiper

Tags: iphone, view, swipe

Could someone advise what kinda swipe view Groupon are using in the video below and how I could create a similar effect?

[Video Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_NkdNA33oY)

Many Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a paged horizontal UIScrollView, each page with a vertical UIScrollView, and a customised UIPageControl-equivalent on top.  Building your own UIPageControl to work like this is probably a reasonable amount of work.

Comment: Do you know where I could find some sample code? It would be great.

Answer (score 5):

Tom Thorpe has provided an excellent example:
https://github.com/TomThorpe/UIScrollSlidingPages

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the way I've done it is two paged horizontal UIScrollViews. One on the bottom for the content, and one on the top for the header titles (with clip to bounds turned off so that you can see the next and previous headers). Then sync the scroll of the two in the scroll view did scroll methods.